# Magento new order template order date not created

Tags: php, magento

I am saving the new user order in the Magneto and sending order email. Everything is ok but the order date is not coming in the template. The variable in the order_new.phtml is {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}  which is generating and exception "No date part in '' " due to which the order email body is coming as blank. Can somebody suggest me about this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by long but try this one {{var order.created_at}} it will give you this output: 2013-02-25 17:19:50. Tested on 1.7.2 version.

Regards,

Comment: Its working but why this is not working:order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}

Comment: I did some tests and it worked for me I got this: 25 lutego 2013 18:32:50 CET from this {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}

Comment: Actually i have a custom plugin in which i am sending the order email after successful payment. In this case this is coming as blank and order email template is breaking due to which... Can you help me?

Comment: What about different vars in your template are they ok?

Comment: Ok I can help you out but I need access to your dev env :)